# XXX is not a function in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

I have a problem with understanding how javascript and jquery functions works.
In my code i have functions defined as

```
FunctionName: function()
{
//function body
},
```

when i am trying to add new function above and then access it i occur error FunctionName is not a function.
My code looks like:

```
handleHash: function() {
//body
},
handleHashChange: function() {
//body
this.handleHash();
//body    
 },
anotherFunction: function(){
this.handleHash();
//body
},
```

I occur mentioned error in handleHashChange, but it works perfectly fine with anotherFunction

Why is that?
Thank you from advance

Comment: are you trying to define your functions as methods of an object. or simple functions?

Comment: Please show the wrapper code too.

Comment: Send the whole code. It looks like you are writing those functions inside an Object!

Comment: I don't know because i am newbie an i am working on existing project.

Comment: There are a lot of mistakes in the code!

Comment: You need to show more code, the odds are you ARE defining methods of an object, but its hard to be sure with only this code

Comment: @PrzemekJacekJastrowicz send the whole code in which those functions are written!